# how do I access Chrome Developer Console from Selenium

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use the chrome web developer tool javascript console function `performance.timing.domComplete` within an automated test using something like this:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("performance.timing.domComplete"));
```

I'm using C# , Webdriver and  Chrome

I think maybe one of these timing values could be used for a Wait function or monitoring performance within a test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real clear on what your question is, but if you are looking for a way to do Waits with WebDriver, take a look at the [Webinator](http://webinator.codeplex.com/) project (available on nuget), it has a lot of wait options like:

```
Web.Click(LocateBy.Id("submitForm"), WaitUntil.AjaxOrPostCompleted());
Web.Click(LocateBy.Name("addClient"), DelayUntil.Displayed(LocateBy.Id("someId")));
```

If you are wanting to roll your own, you will likely need to inject javascript that detects the `onbeforeunload` and `ready` events and notifies WebDriver accordingly.